# How to pass a "function pointer"/ event to a child element in Polymer/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, paper-elements

I have created a generic "create X dialog" component that uses paper-dialog and I want to send the generic component the specific action that i want called when the "create button" is fired.

How do I send function / event around in polymer? I am approaching this the wrong way? The polymer dos [talk about listeners and firing](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) but i am not sure how to apply that in this example, perhaps I am just missing a key point on that page?

```html
<dom-module id="my-add-dialog">

  <template>

    <style>
    </style>

    <paper-dialog id="dialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <p>{{description}}</p>

      <paper-button raisedButton id="test" label="Click" on-click="createGeneric">
      </paper-button>

    </paper-dialog>


  </template>

  </script>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-add-dialog',


      properties: {
        createVirtual: {
          type: Function
        },

      },

      createGeneric: function() {
        alert("I'm alive");
        createVirtual();
      },

      open: function() {
        this.$.dialog.open();
      }


    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

component that composes that:

```html
<dom-module id="my-add-model-dialog">

  <template>
    <my-add-dialog id="dialog" title = "Acount Creation" description="Create Account" createVirtual="createmodel"></my-add-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-add-model-dialog',

      open: function(){
        this.$.dialog.open();
      },

      createmodel: function(){
        alert("Creating a model");
      },


    });
  </script>


</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [declaratively add an event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners) to a Polymer element, insert an attribute in the form of:

```
    <custom-element on-EVENTNAME="METHODNAME">
```

where:

- *EVENTNAME* is the **lowercase** name of the event to listen to (e.g., `tap`, `click`, `blur`, `my-custom-event`).
- *METHODNAME* is the **case-sensitive** name of the event handler method.

Then, the element (or its child elements) can trigger that event with [`this.fire('EVENTNAME')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#custom-events):

```
    <dom-module id="custom-element">
        ...
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'custom-element',
                foo: function() {
                    this.fire('my-custom-event');
                },
                ...
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
```

#### Example

Using your code as an example...

1. Listen to `create` events on `my-add-model-dialog`, binding `createmodel()` as an event handler:

   ```
   <my-add-model-dialog on-create="createmodel"></my-add-model-dialog>
   ```
2. In `my-add-dialog`, fire the `create` event, which bubbles up to `my-add-model-dialog`, invoking `createmodel()`.

   ```
   <script>
     Polymer({
       is: 'my-add-dialog',

       createGeneric: function() {
         alert("I'm alive");
         this.fire('create');
       },
       ...
     });
   </script>
   ```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-add-model-dialog></my-add-model-dialog>

  <dom-module id="my-add-dialog">
    <template>
      <paper-dialog id="dialog" with-backdrop>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <paper-button raised on-click="createGeneric">Create</paper-button>
      </paper-dialog>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-add-dialog',
  
        createGeneric: function() {
          alert("I'm alive");
          this.fire('create');
        },
  
        open: function() {
          this.$.dialog.open();
        },
  
        ready: function() {
          this.open();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-add-model-dialog">
    <template>
      <my-add-dialog id="dialog" title="Account Creation" description="Create Account" on-create="createmodel"></my-add-dialog>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-add-model-dialog',
  
        open: function() {
          this.$.dialog.open();
        },
  
        createmodel: function() {
          alert("Creating a model");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mamure/edit?html,output)</sup>

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I'd tried the fire function and didn't realise I needed to drop the "on" thank you so much! Consider the penny dropped!

Comment: @chrispepper1989 no problem